# Apache Poi - Writing Foreign Characters To Excel 97/2003 (i.e. Chinese, Japanese, etc)

Tags: java, unicode, apache-poi

I am trying to write some foreign character to an Excel 97/2003 file (i.e. Chinese, Japanese, Korean, etc) and am having trouble. I have tried a lot and nothing seems to work. Is it possible? My code for writing this cell is below.

```
HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Sample sheet");
...

HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(0);
HSSFCell firstCell = row.createCell((short)0);
HSSFFont theFont = workbook.createFont();                                      
theFont.setFontName("Arial Unicode MS");                                               
HSSFCellStyle style =  workbook.createCellStyle();                                 
style.setFont(theFont);
firstCell.setCellStyle(style);                      
firstCell.setCellValue(firstColVal);
```

Answer (score 0):

POI has supported Unicode characters in Excel for at least 5 years, maybe longer! (I can't remember exactly). Almost all the people having problems of late with POI and Unicode turn out to be using versions of POI that slightly pre-date the discovery of fire and the wheel... (I only half joke!)

Firstly, make sure you are using a recent version of Apache POI. As of September 2013, I'd suggest you try POI 3.10 beta 2, which is the most recent release. You can always find the most recent version on the [POI download page](http://poi.apache.org/download.html).

Secondly, make sure you're actually using the version of POI you mean to. Lots of people forget to remove old copies from their classpath, and end up still using a previous release because Java will tend to pick the first jar it comes across if there are two with the same library in. See [this POI FAQ entry](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10006) for how to check what version you're actually using.

Finally, just set unicode strings in your file as normal. If you're using a non-standard font, ensure that it supports the code points you use, but then that's no different to Excel itself!

POI has a number of unit tests which verify automatically that it correctly handles unicode text. See things like [TestUnicodeWorkbook](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/testcases/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/TestUnicodeWorkbook.java) and [TextHSSFHeaderFooter](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/testcases/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/TestHSSFHeaderFooter.java) if you want to re-assure yourself that it's working properly.

Comment: I have the newest version of POI and always have, and currently it is the 3.10 Beta, which I updated three days ago. The problem may be in the string itself. For some reason, it's showing up as the ? before writing to Excel.

Comment: `the ? before writing to Excel` makes it sound like you're trying to print it out to the console or similar? Make sure the encoding of your JVM is correctly set, and your console has a suitable font, otherwise you can get misleading messages/logs out